# how to select top ID from join operation and staging tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this inner join from staging and operations table jobsCode  I want to select the top surrogate key ID and get the Start_Date from this join my problem is my Query rerunning 2 records[image]
original query

```
SELECT a.JobCode 
    ,b.ID
    ,b.Start_Date   
    ,a.EndDate  
    ,b.Start_Date  
    ,b.End_Date
FROM [RPStage].[dbo].[GLBJobCode] a 
    INNER JOIN [operations].[dbo].[Job_Code] b ON  a.JobCode =  b.Job_Code
        AND a.EndDate = b.End_Date
        AND a.EndDate = '9998-12-31'
        AND a.StartDate != b.Start_Date;
```

trying to get it using max function

```
SELECT a.JobCode 
    ,MAX(b.ID) ID
    ,MAX(B.Start_Date) Start_Date  
    ,a.EndDate  
    ,b.Start_Date  
    ,b.End_Date
FROM [Stage].[dbo].[JobCode] a 
    INNER JOIN [operations].[dbo].[Job_Code] b ON  a.JobCode =  b.Job_Code
        AND a.EndDate = b.End_Date
        AND a.EndDate = '9998-12-31'
        AND a.StartDate != b.Start_Date
GROUP BY a.JobCode
    ,b.ID
    ,a.EndDate
    ,b.Start_Date
    ,b.End_Date;
```

Comment: Do you want the `MAX(b.ID)` or the `MAX(b.Start_Date)`? These could belong to different rows.

Comment: I am trying to get both to do update opreation

Comment: You need to find IDs first and query for the date. Using MAX won't work here since it returns every non-unique combination for non grouping columns.

Answer (score 1):

## Window Functions, or the OVER() Clause

It appears that what you are looking for is a [window function or an `OVER()` clause.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx)

In your original example, you are trying to use two `max()` conditions, which doesn't work, because when you try to then apply `GROUP BY`, you can have a condition where the max of the first column `ID` and the second column `startdate` aren't in the same row, and so then `GROUP BY` simply can't be understood.

However, if you are looking to extract the max over a grouping, and you can define that grouping, and you want to obtain the 'column-wise' maximum for more than one column for that grouping (as you seem to want to do), then here's the solution.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
  jobcode integer,
  id integer, 
  a_startdate datetime,
  a_enddate datetime,
  b_startdate datetime,
  b_enddate datetime);

  INSERT INTO test VALUES (513801, 7136, '11-01-2011', '12-31-9998', '11-01-2011', '12-31-9998');
  INSERT INTO test VALUES (513801, 7137,'04-26-2014', '12-31-9998','04-26-2014', '12-31-9998');
```

I first made this table to recreate your input data in the picture.  I then applied this query.

```
SELECT jobcode, max(id) OVER (PARTITION BY jobcode), 
max(a_startdate) OVER(PARTITION BY jobcode), 
a_enddate,  b_startdate, b_enddate FROM test;
```

Try out this **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7b022/1)**, and see if it gives the results you're looking for.  I did the best I could with the description I had.

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping by `b.Start_Date` and for each row aggregate `MAX(B.Start_Date)` always the same as `b.Start_Date`. Just replace `b.Start_Date` with `a.Start_Date`

```
SELECT a.JobCode 
    ,MAX(b.ID) ID
    ,MAX(B.Start_Date) Start_Date  
    ,a.EndDate  
    ,a.Start_Date  
FROM [Stage].[dbo].[JobCode] a 
INNER JOIN [operations].[dbo].[Job_Code] b ON  a.JobCode =  b.Job_Code
    AND a.EndDate = b.End_Date
    AND a.EndDate = '9998-12-31'
    AND a.StartDate != b.Start_Date
GROUP BY a.JobCode
    ,b.ID
    ,a.EndDate
    ,a.Start_Date;
```

Comment: still I have same result all